# Where to use the default cursor and pointer cursor in button and label?

Tags: buttons, cursor, default

In google drive i found some buttons and labels are found to be inconsistent in cursors.

[image]
[image]

Are there commonly accepted conventions as to default cursors and pointer cursors in web and desktop applications?

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/whether-to-use-pointer-hand-over-a-button-or-just-the-default-cursor - in short, they use hand every time clicking leads to another view, and pointer whenever it just triggers some function within the current view. I have mixed feelings about it, though.

Answer (score 2):

In desktop or web application the default cursor is always been a convention for a button, for example, in HTML the default cursor for the button object is the default setting: if you want a pointer, you have to specify it via CSS.

It's all about **affordance**: the button object has a strong affordance, the user knows that it's an interactive object and how it works, as you can read on the [Microsoft's guidelines for developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545459.aspx):

> *"[...]command buttons already have a strong affordance, so they
>   don't need a hand pointer. The hand pointer must mean "this target is
>   a link" and nothing else."*

Although it is a convention, it's actually common to use the hand pointer: StackExchange does it too.